# Target x86 instead of x64?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Using QtCreator with visual studio 2013 x64 kit (which I think contains compilers for both 32 bit and 64 bit)

How can I tell it to specifically target 32 bit instead of 64 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2013 x64 kit only contains a configuration for one compiler. You can check out the kit details in the settings dialog (Build and Run category -> Kits tab). When you select the Visual Studio 2013 x64 kit, you can see the configured compiler in the bottom (it most probably is Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (x64)).
For a x86 build you  will need to setup an appropriate Visual Studio 2013 x86 kit containing the respective x86 compiler, debugger and Qt version and select this kit for the project.

Comment: Followup question... I also need msys+mingw for other stuff, so I could use that kit instead. Is there a major reason to choose one vs. the other (mingw vs. visual studio 2013)?

Comment: I pretty much only have experience with Visual Studio, so I cannot really say much about mingw. There are similar questions on SO about this topic already (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203104/windows-qt-with-mingw-or-visual-studios). Overall it should mostly depend on your environment (e.g. do you need C++ features not available in one of them, do you already have dependencies that use one or the other, etc.).